# Haxe: How can I setup a class to store data in an array of type that I pass in the constructor

Tags: android, flashdevelop, haxe, openfl

I am coding in Haxe, Lime, OpenFl.  I am trying to set up a Class to store data in a Map, referenced by class instance. The class type is to be passed in the constructor, via inference. But I am quite new to all this and can't quite figure out the syntax, this is what I got so far:

```
class DynamicStore<A>
{
    private var hashA:Map<Class<A>,String>;

    public function new<A>(paramA:Class<A>) {
        hashA = new Map();
    }
}
```

But this gives me the following error:

Abstract Map has no @:to function that accepts IMap<Class<DynamicStore.A>, String>

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A question first:

> do you really want to use classes as key? or objects?

**In classes should be the key**

It would be much simpler to use the classe's full name as key, like "mypackage.blob.MyClass". It's safer, easier to handle and debug.

`Map<String, String>`

Would suffice in that case.

**If objects should be keys**

Then the code would look like:

```
import haxe.ds.ObjectMap;

class Test<A>
{
    static function main() {}

    private var hashA :ObjectMap<A,String>;

    public function new(paramA:A) {
        hashA = new ObjectMap<A,String>();
    }
}
```

The reason "Map" cannot be directly used in this case is that "Map" is a syntactic sugar, being resolved to StringMap, IntMap or others depending on the key type. If it doesn't know what kind of map to be used, it cannot proceed (this is mainly due to cross-compiling issues).

**Remark**

As a final note, I would mention your construction seems a bit wacky/strange to me. It would be interesting to know what you are trying to achieve and why you structure it the way you do.

Comment: The ultimate goal is to build a class that can take 1 or more class types and use combinations of them to generate id's that are specific to each combination of the defined classes instances (classA:instanceX,classB:instanceY,classC:instanceZ) generates id number:J and can then fetch that id by passing in the three instances, or fetch all instance of class A that have keys created with classB and classC and so forth.  I was planning to achieve this largely with objectmaps.

Comment: The solution you provided worked for me, when used your code, but made one change:
hashA = new ObjectMap<A,String>()  was changed to:
hashA = new ObjectMap();  otherwise it gave me an error.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can use Class as the key of a Map. A good work around it to use a String as a key and the fully qualified names of the types. You can also define an abstract to move from the Type to String easily ... something like the following (code not-tested);

```
private var hashA : Map<String, String>;

public function addClass(className : ClassId, ...)
```

And the abstract will look something like this:

```
abstract ClassId(String) {
  inline public function new(name : String) this = name;
  @:from public static inline function fromClass(cls : Class<Dynamic>)
    return new ClassId(Type.getClassName(cls));
  @:to public inline function toClass() : Class<Dynamic>
    return Type.resolveClass(this);
  @:to public inline function toString() : String
    return this;
}
```